# What do App Store reviewers say about greyed out buttons leading to in app purchases?

Tags: applications, apple

I'm wondering if there's anyone that have any experience from submitting an in app purchases (IAP) based iOS app to Apple with greyed out buttons that leads to the actual purchase?

I've been searching but haven't found much, but it seems Apple is a little bit concerned and they rather see the greyed out buttons as dark as possible to not interfere too much with the UX...

Comment: Why would it be grayed out to begin with? I'm not sure I understand the entire question.